# Linked the third-party static library twice when use UnityFramework

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

- unity 2019.4
- Cocoapods 1.10.1
- xcode 12.5

**Podfile:**

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
use_frameworks!

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'AppsFlyerFramework', '~> 6.2.4'
end

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end
```

**run log**

```
objc[5990]: Class AppsFlyerProxyManager is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97237BCE-C78A-4C22-8DE2-19D7CC866571/dev.app/dev (0x102d6b4c0) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97237BCE-C78A-4C22-8DE2-19D7CC866571/dev.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x10c670350). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5990]: Class AppsFlyerCrossPromotionHelper is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97237BCE-C78A-4C22-8DE2-19D7CC866571/dev.app/dev (0x102d6b510) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/97237BCE-C78A-4C22-8DE2-19D7CC866571/dev.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (0x10c6703a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

AppsFlyerFramework is static library

```
$ file Versions/A/AppsFlyerLib
Versions/A/AppsFlyerLib: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures: [i386:current ar archive] [arm_v7] [x86_64] [arm64]
Versions/A/AppsFlyerLib (for architecture i386):    current ar archive
Versions/A/AppsFlyerLib (for architecture armv7):   current ar archive
Versions/A/AppsFlyerLib (for architecture x86_64):  current ar archive
Versions/A/AppsFlyerLib (for architecture arm64):   current ar archive
```

I tried to solve this problem:modify the Podfile as follows:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
use_frameworks!

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'AppsFlyerFramework', '~> 6.2.4'
end

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end

static_frameworks = ['AppsFlyerFramework']
# make all the static frameworks into static frameworks by overriding the static_framework? function to return true
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    puts pod.name
    if static_frameworks.include?(pod.name)
      puts "Overriding the static_framework? method for #{pod.name}"
      def pod.static_framework?;
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it didn't solve the problem

UnityFramework is dynamic library。Unity-iPhone depends on UnityFramework. UnityFramework depends on third-party framework

UnityFramework already linked the third-party static library.How to prevent Unity-iPhone to link the third-part static library.

My English is not good, if there is a description is not clear, I will add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem.

1. UnityFramework is a dynamic framework, It Must link dependent 3Party libraries If you declare and use them in source codes.
2. You must make sure Unity-iPhone didn't link the same framework as UnityFramework.

If there are any other solutions, notify me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30582182)